# How to write custom routes with regex in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In routes.rb we already have route like this:

```
get 'articles/*article_name', to: 'article_details#show'
```

But we need another routes(like below) which needs to be redirected to some other controller.

```
get 'articles/sitemap*', to: 'article/sitemap#show'
```

The url may have anything after sitemap( **articles/sitemap-abc, articles/sitemap-bcd** ).

How to achieve this?

Comment: Look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your article_name route:

```
get 'articles/:sitemap', to: 'articles/sitemap#show', sitemap: /sitemap-.+/
```

I assume your controller is `articles` and fix that in the route above, if I'm wrong, you could change it back to `article`.

Doc here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints